# Using a dummy variable to keep a count

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, partition

I have a user (X) who has been sent 15 emails.  There is a field called Opened which is 1 or 0 depending if he opened the emails.  I want to work down the list (ordered by date) and start a count each time I get to zero i.e. count each time he gets an email until he opens it.  Then I want to average out all the counts.  I have tried partitioning and various things but nothing works.

Sorry if I am putting this in the wrong place.  This is my final code, should anyone want to do something similar.

Declare @UserCount as Int
Declare @counter as int
Declare @StartEnd as varchar(10)

SET @counter=1
SET @UserCount=1

```
--Step through the table by user
WHILE @UserCount < (SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM #Stage2)
BEGIN
    --UserProcessOrder is the row number - update the dummy parameter @StartEnd
    SET @StartEnd = (SELECT TOP(1) StartEnd FROM #Stage2 WHERE UserProcessOrder=@UserCount)

    --Update the table with the counter value
    UPDATE #Stage2 SET MaxBeforeOpen=@counter where UserProcessOrder=@UserCount

    --Add 1 to the counter so that every time we see START we add 1
    SET @Counter = @counter+1

    --If we are at the end of the group then re-set the counter
    IF @StartEnd='END'  SET @counter = 1

    --Go to next record for that user
    SET @UserCount=@UserCount+1
END
```

--select * from #Stage2

SELECT AVG(MaxBeforeOpen) as AverageEmailsBeforeOpen
FROM
(
SELECT *
from #Stage2
WHERE StartEnd='END'
) as x

Comment: Hey Kathy, can you give us  a little bit more information about what you are wanting the report/query to look like and what type of SQL back-end do you have MS SQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, or something else?

Comment: Showing your own efforts also will be great))

Comment: Table definitions and sample data, and wanted result also,

Comment: Hi,  I tried to add a table but wasn't allowed as I have only just registered.  Sorry.  I'm using MS SQL.  I will try to explain the table that I am using

Comment: UserID   Date  Opened  REQUIRED  - I have 1's and zero's in the Opened field and I want it to run a count in 'Required' field where Opened is 0 then re-start the count each time it gets to a 1 in Opened.  This would be a lot easier if I could just show you a table

Comment: @Kathy Are you trying to insert an image of the table into the question? If so, post the link in a comment (that should work regardless of rep, I think) and one of us can edit it in for you.